# Multi-tenant JavaScript application with tenant specific bundles

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm investigating ways to build a multi-tenant JS web application. I was hoping to be able to import files as follows.

```
import Thing from './thing'
```

I want to configure webpack/babel/*a tool* to look for a file specific to the tenant first, i.e. `thing.tenant.js`, then falling back to `thing.js`.

A similar approach to platform-specific code in react-native, except the tenant, would be supplied as part of the build and end up with its own bundle `bundle.tenant.js`.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: I think you need a wrapper over `import` for that. Something like `tenantImport("./thing")` and implement the logic you mention in `tenantImport`

Comment: @Adelin, thanks, this is a good option. I've seen a couple of implementations of this. 

I am still digging into the react-native code to see how they do it for the `filename.{platform}.js`, but it's a big codebase and I've not had much luck finding anything.

Comment: @benembery Did you have any luck finding a workable solution?

Comment: @TimRogers we’re still looking at ways to do this better but the approach suggested by Adelin is what we’ve used so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So we've finally got a solution in place for this. We return an array of webpack configurations in our config file.

Using webpack merge we combined our shared configuration with a tenant-specific configuration. We made a method that generates these to keep the configuration more succinct.

For each tenant we custom extensions array in resolve to get it to first look for a file with the tenant extension as follows.

```
  {
    resolve: {
      extensions: [`.${tenant}.js`, ".js"]
    }
  }
```

This means when our code imported a module like so

```
import Header from './header'
```

Webpack would first look for `header.{tenant}.js` and then ask for `tenant.js`.

We applied the same principle to our sass imports however, we are currently a forked version of [sass-loader](https://github.com/benembery/sass-loader) to achieve the same thing with sass.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,

            use: [
                // Loaders omitted for brevity...
                {
                    loader: "sass-loader",
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                        extensions: [`.${tenant}.scss`, ".scss", ".sass", ".css"],
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
   ]
}
```

This gave us 90% of what we needed. But build times were **slow** as multiple configurations means multiple webpack runs. To mitigate this we started using the [webpack hard source plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hard-source-webpack-plugin) which made the build time much more acceptable. The following configuration is added to the plugins configuration.

```
new HardSourceWebpackPlugin({
    configHash: (webpackConfig) => {
            const config = {
                webpackConfig,
                // our custom config merged in here...
            }
            return require('node-object-hash')({
                sort: false
            }).hash(config);
    },
})
```

Comment: Hii, if you need to add some element on a specific component and this element should be copied to every client. What's the best way to sync that change for every existing client ?

Comment: @VitorCamancho I not sure I fully understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Imagine I have two components UserDeitails.tsx and UserDetails.tenant1.tsx and their show a list of details of a user. Since I only want to add one detail in particular on tenant1, I need to fully copy the content of the default component and paste on tenant1 and add the extra detail, or there's another approach to that? The question is, how we maintain the code sync with the default component, since every general change should me made on the default and inherit by the tenants.

Comment: I've not found an easy way to do I'm afraid. However, sometimes it's possibles to break down the customisations into smaller components or take them as props. I hope this helps